# How is this requesting personal medical advice?

Tags: discussion

The question titled [Somatosensation](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/17489/somatosensation) was flagged in my review queue by 2 people, presumably including @Narusan due to the comment, and I am wondering how it is requesting personal medical advice.

I have skipped review on this for now as I have looked at the [edit history](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/posts/17489/revisions) too in order to see if it was relating to an old edit, and I am still at a loss.

Comment: This is the same as this question: https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/958/8212 OP gives a bunch of *symptoms*, and want's a *diagnosis*. That's off-topic here. I feel like personal medical diagnosis comes closest

Comment: @Narusan, the root to the question you linked starts with *"I was recently involved in a traffic accident. It was a sudden stop, and the airbags were deployed...."* which I would agree leads to a question regarding said accident.  The question linked in my question here does not seem to bear any resemblance to me to a question seeking advice on a particular medical problem the OP is suffering from.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm a bit in the middle on this one. On one hand it looks like they could be looking for a diagnosis for an individual (off-topic), on the other hand if their question would be just slightly more polished (for example, if they related it to some other similar-but-different conditions, maybe congenital insensitivity to pain) I would take it as an on-topic terminology question looking for an answer in the family of hereditary sensory neuropathies.

Comment: @ChrisRogers It's the same as the case I presented in my answer to that question (should have linked the answer, not the question): *The patient is experiencing symptoms A-Z, what can be the cause?* is always asking for a diagnosis, and regardless if it is for OP, for OP's best friend or for OP to help them learn, we have decided that this is off-topic.

Comment: @BryanKrause I think a good question would be the other way around: *What are symptoms of the Brown-Sequard-Syndrome, and how are they caused* as an example.

Comment: I believe I follow now where the problem lies and now agree.  I too now have voted for closure.

Comment: @Narusan I agree. I still do feel like it's possible to ask for the name of a syndrome with a description of symptoms and stay on-topic, but it would require more background research that shows it's clear the OP knows what the issue is but is looking for the name (rather than simply having a list of symptoms). Some of the more rare/bizarre cases might be difficult to find names for, especially where names may be inconsistent across languages or something.